# iPhone/iPad - IP traffic statistics per application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ip, traffic-measurement

Is it possible to get access to real-time IP traffic statistics generator by each application running on the the iPhone/iPad?

Failing this, is there such thing as transparent proxy software that runs on the device that can collect this information?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible on iOS without jailbreak.

If you would like to count the traffic in "Your App", you should be able to do this with a reasonable effort.
But not for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS model doesn't allow you to view the information of another applications.  Each application runs in its own space.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the network connections of your own app using the "Instruments"-App installed with Xcode. ("I/O Activity" -> "Network Connections")